# How do I hook in a post validate function in a form element

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing a more advanced file form element, more of a widget that displays the currently loaded uploaded image as well as validating image sizes etc.

If the file validates, I want the form element itself to copy the file to a publicly accessible folder. This will mean that a) the image can be displayed and b) if the whole form doesn't validate, the user does not need to re-upload the image.

Anyway that's the back story, but essentially I need to figure out how to get a function from within a form element to run when the form validates that element. Something like creating an onValidate() function in the form element class.

Most importantly I need a solution that doesn't spill out into the controller (or as little as possible). I am struggling to find a clean way to implement this.

I would like to do something like this...

```
class File extends Element implements InputProviderInterface
{

....

public function isValid()
{
    if ( $isValid = parent::isValid() ) {
        echo "Hi there, glad you called";
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Zend\Form\Element::getValidator()` function will be called on each validation run.

I think you should call a class which's concern it is to copy the file.
Maybe you want to raise an event to make it more decoupled.

Validation and Filtering are now part of the InputFilter class.
Your goal is to write an dedicated Validator and hardwire it with your Element.

An example of how to achieve this, look at [Zend\Form\Element\Select](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/Element/Select.php) which as a hardwired `InArrayValidator` in its `onValidate()` method.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, I ended up creating a filter that would action. After spending a lot of time exhaustively trying to create an InputFilter, I found that the InputFilter class itself was just a structure for validators and filters. I don't really like my solution as I think that putting action code in a filter isn't a very good way of doing things. But I wanted some encapsulation. I think in a few months time of using ZF2 I'll be able to come back and refactor.

Comment: Hmm, maybe your Validator could raise an 'FileValides' event, which is then picked up by a class dedicated to providing and copying these files. alternativley the validator could just call it after validating successful. just don't forget to inject that class.